# Ryzen System Freezing When Under Heavy Load

Tags: performance, cpu, cpu-load, amd-processor

I have been having problems with my system completely locking up (no keyboard or mouse input, no display output change) when the CPU is under heavy load e.g. Tensorflow or Raytracing with Blender. I can reproduce the problem with both tasks on Ubuntu 18.04. However, rendering the same scene under Windows 10 has been unable to reproduce the problem. Additionally, appears as if the CPU is being throttled slightly more by Windows. It sits at 76% utilisation when rendering on Windows, vs around 10% more on Ubuntu.

Can anyone suggest how I could fix this?

I originally made [a post in the MSI forums](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=307387.msg1774289#msg1774289) but it appears that it may be a Linux issue and so have posted it here.

## Full system information

```
Board:   MSI X370 Gaming Plus
BIOS:    E7A33AMS.5C0
CPU:     AMD Ryzen 7 2700x
GPU:     MSI Gaming X GTX 1080TI
PSU:     XFX TS70 750W 80+ Gold (12V 62A 744W)
RAM:     1x16GB Ballistix Sport DDR4 2400 1.2V
Cooler:  Stock AMD Ryzen (In box)
HDD/SSD: WD Blue 250GB M.2 SSD, Kingston A4500 120GB SATA SSD, 2TB Seagate Barracuda 3.5" SATA III HDD
OS:      Ubuntu 18.04 (Main), Windows 10
```

## Commands run while rendering

### free

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        1.0G         13G        9.9M        1.6G         14G
Swap:          4.7G          0B        4.7G
```

### uptime

```
 12:52:56 up 11 min,  3 users,  load average: 10.03, 3.37, 1.28
```

### top

```
top - 12:52:56 up 11 min,  3 users,  load average: 10.51, 3.58, 1.36
Tasks: 282 total,   1 running, 181 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 10.8 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 87.8 id,  1.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16432192 total, 13716960 free,  1087124 used,  1628108 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4881404 total,  4881404 free,        0 used. 15024944 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 3577 john      20   0 10.327g 270760 143720 S  1406  1.6  16:27.58 blender
    1 root      20   0  225180   8880   6656 S   0.0  0.1   0:01.10 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
    6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.09 rcu_sched
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0
   12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1
```

### dmesg

[Full output here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tyenufwhkh2kbke/dmesg.txt?dl=0)

### lm-sensors (temperatures)

```
k10temp-pci-00c3
AdapterL PCI adapter
temp1:        +74.2°C  (high = +70.0°C)
```

Comment: what is the output of `free -h` , `uptime`, and the first several lines of top when under load?

Comment: @j-money Here is a screenshot of my machine rendering a scene in blender with free, uptime and top visible: https://imgur.com/a/nE25aev

Comment: In my last screenshot top was showing strange output. It usually has blender at 1550% cpu as here: https://imgur.com/a/9SukvAw

Comment: Erm can you post it in a text file rather than a picture? or just in your op. Also the output of `dmesg`

Comment: @j-money I've added the information to the op

Comment: hmmm try this `for i in 1 2 3 4;do while: ;d do : ; done & done`. Does the system still lock up? Also you should see 100% utilization on 4 cores.

Comment: Just to clarify it doesn't lock up immediately when running, only after a few minutes. Could be a thermal shutdown? The display keeps the last image before locking up, the fans spin down a little , and and there no keyboard or mouse input response.

Comment: I can't really say either way on that as I don't know what the thermals are like when running blender. But the script I gave you should utilize all four cores (or is it 6 for ryzen chips?) at 100% until the end of time (or you kill it manually). I haven't really seen anything that would point to ubuntu as the problem, though maybe a fresh install would help?

Comment: Tried script in your comment but bash complains with: unexpected token `done'. This CPU has 8 cores (16 virtual). This is a fairly fresh install. Only had it for a couple of weeks and installed a few applications. I can log the thermals with lm-sensors. E.g. it reported ~74C while rendering on Ubuntu (high is > 70C). I think the limit is 95C but people online report cut offs ranging from 72-95C.

Comment: The same task on Windows across cores averages about 10% less utilisation than Ubuntu and doesn't freeze up. Led me to believe it might be a thermal throttling issue. I will try rendering on windows again and see if temperatures average lower too.

Comment: hmm get rid of the d after the while. Also with those thermals I can't really say either way if it is being shut down due to thermals. On my personal machine (which runs arch) I've been able to get upwards of +80ish without noticing (aside from third degree burns)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82798/discussion-between-j-money-and-john-p).

Comment: Ok, I tried again on Windows for comparison. This time the temperature rose to 81.5C (using AMD Ryzen Master Utility) and the CPU load was 83% across all cores (all at 83%, which gradually declined to around 80% after sever minutes), 100% PPT (total socket power, 141W), 95% TDC (sustained current limit, 95A) throughout the render. This utility also reports the max temperature as 95C. So very similar numbers to under Ubuntu but without any freezing up. I know there have been kernel issues in the past with linux and Ryzen so it looks likely to be a software / driver thing to me still.

Comment: @JohnP Did you ever get the problem resolved? We're seeing the exact problem on a brand new machine here.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I think I may have! Just in the last few days I've not had any problems so far since making sure to disable all of the power saving (cool n quiet) and C-state options in the BIOS. Additionally, I put the vcore back to auto which I had set to manual because the bios was setting it very high (~1.4v) and the only way to make it stable was to set a manual limit. My EDC peak current is still oddly at 100% all the time in rysen master which I don't quite understand but may be to do with the power saving options being disabled. EDIT: Typo fix. Please let me know if you need more info